# Stacks like display:block, but retains width of text inside - is this possible?

Tags: html, list, css

I'm trying to create a navigation list where all the list items stack on top of one another, as per display:block, but where their width is influenced by the width of the text within them, as per display:inline.

It seems like I can only choose one or the other - I've tried setting the li and li a to various combinations of block/inline/inline-block and it's not working. Either my list items are all the same width, or they're sitting next to each other instead of on top of one another.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve and can't:
http://i39.tinypic.com/280t5s0.png

Is this possible to do? I feel like it really should be but am completely stumped and searching hasn't turned up much.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks and best wishes,

Emma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Long Item 2</li>
    <li>Longer Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

[See it live](http://jsfiddle.net/7Cf8g/)

Comment: Hi @Dark Falcon ... if I may ask... what is the clear right for in this bit of code? Not sure what I'm missing... seems to work in the fiddle without it.

Comment: Not having the `clear: right` in my browser causes them to be on the same line. `clear: right` ensures that the element is below any other `float: right` element above it in the HTML.

Comment: I see, what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox on Linux. Are you sure you pressed the Run button after making this change? This is pretty standard behavior.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it didn't run my code when I changed it, I can see how this works now, thanks.